# R combo box for selecting numbe of clusterring

Tags: r, gwidgets

How to fill a combo box with numbers like 2,3,4,5 ,when the user select the number  , after that  a button coded with clustering will take the value from the combo box to do the selected number of clustering.

Need help .

Comment: Please clarify your question, include some code and have a look at [**How to make a great R reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: Great that it's solved! If you would like, you can post the solution below as an answer and accept it. If you'd prefer not to, please consider removing the question.

Comment: tbl[2,3] =gedit("", container=tbl, coerce.with=as.numeric) . Through this code  i had asked the user to enter how many cluster thy want to  enter.  Then  i had called them in  a function   of a button   cl1=clara(ssv,svalue(tbl[2,3]))   ,to do the clustering.

Comment: Hay Ben can u  suggest  me  where  to  find  a  easier codes to understand R ,for making a GUI or anything . I m 1 month old in R  ,so  my company asked me to create a  Clustering tool  .

Comment: For a while, I was using Tcl/Tk (good examples at http://www.sciviews.org/_rgui/tcltk/index.html). Recently, I've been delving into [Shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/) for browser-based interactive analyses with R. Good luck!

Comment: Well  thanks for it Ben , well Shiny seems to  be web based ,so dont thnk  it will help be mre .............do u have sumthng related to  r gwidgetsrgtk ...........

Answer (score 2):

In case someone wants an answer, here is a sketch using `gWidgets2`:

```
w <- gwindow()
g <- gvbox(cont=w)
e <- gedit("5", cont=g, coerce=as.integer)
cb <- gcombobox(1:5, cont=g)
b <- gbutton("do clustering", cont=g)

addHandlerChanged(e, handler=function(h,...) {
  ## check svalue(e) is non-NA
  cb[] <- seq_len(svalue(e))
})

addHandlerClicked(b, handler=function(h,...) {
  print(sprintf("Do clustering with %s", svalue(cb)))
})
```